# What's the alternative to Symfony render(controller) in Laravel

Tags: laravel, symfony, laravel-blade

In Symfony I am using widget-like behaviour by calling controller method from twig

```
{{ render(controller(
    'App\\Controller\\ArticleController::recentArticles',
    { 'max': 3 }
)) }}
```

It does the logic and returns another twig template, which is embeded here.

How in the Laravel do people solve this? I need this for displaying menu, responsive menu, product lists, breadcrumbs etc.

I have read about `View composers` and studied the documentation - but there's mentioned only how you can inject some variables into the view.
The same with using `@inject()` in blade.

But I want standalone widget (with own logic, data fetching...) with custom blade template embeded/inserted in any place I call them from.

Thanks for an advice.

Btw. It doesn't need to be Controller that I call, it could be a Service object. But the point is the same. I was personally calling these objects like _WidgetController (beginning with underscore - to tell me, they are not fully qualified views, but components/widgets). But I placed them into my Controllers folder.

Comment: Documentation for Symfony part is here https://symfony.com/doc/4.1/templating/embedding_controllers.html

Comment: why insisting in using a controller as a widget ? that's not how a controller is supposed to work in MVC model. Use the view composers with widget balde template that you overload in your normal template. the result would be the same but more clean and logic

Comment: You can tell the large Symfony community, they are broking the MVC patterns. But I doubt they are. These "widgets" are still models with view called by controller - who said you have to call them by route only. But I was trying to prevent this direction of discussion by saying "it doesn't need to be Controller". I still need examples. I am new to Laravel and I am missing tutorial how exactly do this.